# Stripe - Getting Error in Stripe Method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, afnetworking, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into my app and I followed a tutorial that seems to be out of date. This is how my code looks:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Stripe
import AFNetworking

class PaymentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var expirationDateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cvcTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func payButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Initiate the card
        let stripCard = STPCardParams()

        // Split the expiration date to extract Month & Year
        if self.expirationDateTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            let expirationDate = self.expirationDateTextField.text?.components(separatedBy: "/")
            let expMonth = UInt((expirationDate?[0])!)
            let expYear = UInt((expirationDate?[1])!)

            // Send the card info to Strip to get the token
            stripCard.number = self.cardNumberTextField.text
            stripCard.cvc = self.cvcTextField.text
            stripCard.expMonth = expMonth!
            stripCard.expYear = expYear!
        }

        var underlyingError: NSError?
        stripCard.validateCardReturningError(&underlyingError)
        if underlyingError != nil {
            self.handleError(underlyingError!)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error in this block of code:

```
            var underlyingError: NSError?
        stripCard.validateCardReturningError(&underlyingError)
        if underlyingError != nil {
            self.handleError(underlyingError!)
            return
        }
    }
```

The error says that `.validateCardReturningError(&underlyingError)` is deprecated and that I should use STPCardValidator instead. I tried doing so but could not fix it. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you'll actually need to check the validation state returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to @jflinter . you should flowing this way

```
let cardParams = STPCardParams()
cardParams.number = ...
cardParams.expMonth = ...
cardParams.expYear = ...
cardParams.cvc = ...
if STPCardValidator.validationStateForCard(cardParams) == .Valid {
  // the card is valid.
}
```